# Using explicit (predefined) validation set for grid search with sklearn

Tags: python, validation, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a dataset, which has previously been split into 3 sets: train, validation and test. These sets have to be used as given in order to compare the performance across different algorithms.

I would now like to optimize the parameters of my SVM using the validation set. However, I cannot find how to input the validation set explicitly into `sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV()`. Below is some code I've previously used for doing K-fold cross-validation on the training set. However, for this problem I need to use the validation set as given. How can I do that?

```py
from sklearn import svm, cross_validation
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

# (some code left out to simplify things)

skf = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y_train, n_folds=5, shuffle = True)
clf = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(tol=0.005, cache_size=6000,
                             class_weight=penalty_weights),
                     param_grid=tuned_parameters,
                     n_jobs=2,
                     pre_dispatch="n_jobs",
                     cv=skf,
                     scoring=scorer)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use [`PredefinedSplit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.PredefinedSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.PredefinedSplit)

```
ps = PredefinedSplit(test_fold=your_test_fold)
```

then set `cv=ps` in `GridSearchCV`

> test_fold : “array-like, shape (n_samples,)
>
> test_fold[i] gives the test set fold of sample i. A value of -1 indicates that the corresponding sample is not part of any test set folds, but will instead always be put into the training fold.

Also see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#predefined-fold-splits-validation-sets)

> when using a validation set, set the test_fold to 0 for all samples that are part of the validation set, and to -1 for all other samples.

Comment: If we are doing this, should be replace `clf.fit(X_train, y_train)` by `clf.fit(X, y)`

Comment: @edesz: if `refit=True` in `GridSearchCV` then the OP should know that he cannot use the `GridSearchCV` instance later to predict, because the last thing the instance will do when finished searching for optimal params is to refit the best option to `(X, y)`, but the intention is actually refitting on `(X_train, y_train)`.

Comment: @Corel in this case, I think it's OK to use the instance to predict, but without a visible predictive performance that can be measured from X,y. In this case, I usually split data into train, validation, test first. and then use train + validation to run your approach to select the optimal. I also set refit = True to refit on train + validation. but eventually I will display the predictive performance of them model using test dataset, and use the model(refit on train and validation) to predict.

Answer (score 35):

Consider using the `hypopt` Python package (`pip install hypopt`) for which I am an author. It's a professional package created specifically for parameter optimization with a validation set. It works with any scikit-learn model out-of-the-box and can be used with Tensorflow, PyTorch, Caffe2, etc. as well.

```
# Code from https://github.com/cgnorthcutt/hypopt
# Assuming you already have train, test, val sets and a model.
from hypopt import GridSearch
param_grid = [
  {'C': [1, 10, 100], 'kernel': ['linear']},
  {'C': [1, 10, 100], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['rbf']},
 ]
# Grid-search all parameter combinations using a validation set.
opt = GridSearch(model = SVR(), param_grid = param_grid)
opt.fit(X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val)
print('Test Score for Optimized Parameters:', opt.score(X_test, y_test))
```

EDIT: I (think I) received -1's on this response because I'm suggesting a package that I authored. This is unfortunate, given that the package was created specifically to solve this type of problem.

Comment: hypopt is a great module for hyperparameter search.  A question: how can I specify the metric in hyperparameter search? where do I put like 'auc', 'f1' etc? I posted this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912331/specify-scoring-metric-in-gridsearch-with-hypopt-packge-in-python  @cgnorthcutt

Comment: Answered on the post, but in short, upgrade hypopt package to latest version 1.0.7 and just use the scoring parameter like this `optimizer.fit(X_train, y_train, params, X_val, y_val, scoring='f1'). @zesla

Comment: @cgnorthcutt The scoring parameter for fit function does not work. I am unable to specify scoring = 'f1'.

Comment: That's unusual. Submit a pull request if so please.

Comment: @cgnorthcutt I am getting "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)" error. This same error is there in the GitHub issues list but it is not resolved yet.

Comment: @cgnorthcutt, I am trying oneclasssvm model, but opt.fit(X_train,X_val) does not work. How to make use of this for oneclasssvm? Link to my question: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75051845/using-predefined-self-designed-validation-set-for-parameter-optimization-for-o

Answer (score 22):

```
# Import Libraries
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit

# Split Data to Train and Validation
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.8, stratify = y,random_state = 2020)

# Create a list where train data indices are -1 and validation data indices are 0
split_index = [-1 if x in X_train.index else 0 for x in X.index]

# Use the list to create PredefinedSplit
pds = PredefinedSplit(test_fold = split_index)

# Use PredefinedSplit in GridSearchCV
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator = estimator,
                   cv=pds,
                   param_grid=param_grid)

# Fit with all data
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: See my comment in the accepted answer. You need to be careful not to use `clf` later to predict.

Answer (score 8):

To add to the @Vinubalan's answer, when the train-valid-test split is not done with Scikit-learn's `train_test_split()` function, i.e., the dataframes are already split manually beforehand and scaled/normalized so as to prevent leakage from training data, the numpy arrays can be concatenated.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val = scaler.transform(X_val)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit, GridSearchCV
split_index = [-1]*len(X_train) + [0]*len(X_val)
X = np.concatenate((X_train, X_val), axis=0)
y = np.concatenate((y_train, y_val), axis=0)
pds = PredefinedSplit(test_fold = split_index)

clf = GridSearchCV(estimator = estimator,
                   cv=pds,
                   param_grid=param_grid)

# Fit with all data
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cv` argument of the SearchCV i.e. Grid or Random can just be an iterable of indices too for train and validation split i.e. `cv=((train_idcs, val_idcs),)`.

Note that the data on which the search classifier will be fit should be  the train+val set and the indices specified will be used by the sklearn to separate them internally. Additionally, when working with dataframes, the indices specified should be accessible as ilocs, so reset indices (don't drop them if they will be required later).

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import (
    train_test_split,
    RandomizedSearchCV,
)

data = load_iris(as_frame=True)["frame"]

# These indices will serves as explicit and predefined split
train_idcs, val_idcs = train_test_split(
    data.index, 
    random_state=42, 
    stratify=data.target,
)

param_grid = dict(
    n_estimators=[50,100,150,200],
    max_samples=[0.85,0.9,0.95,1],
    max_depth=[3,5,7,10],
    max_features=["sqrt", "log2", 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1],
)

search_clf = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator=RandomForestClassifier(),
    param_distributions=param_grid,
    n_iter=50,
    cv=((train_idcs, val_idcs),), # explicit predefined split in terms of indices
    random_state=42,
)

# X is the first 4 columns i.e. the sepal and petal widths and lengths
# and y is the 5th column i.e. target column
search_clf.fit(X=data.iloc[:,:4], y=data.target)
```

Also, be mindful if you want to refit on the whole data or only on the train data and thus retrain the classifier using the best fit parameters accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide some reproducible code that creates a validation split using the last 20% of observations.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor

# load data
df_train = datasets.fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True).data
y = datasets.fetch_california_housing().target

param_grid = {"max_depth": [5, 6],
              'learning_rate': [0.03, 0.06],
              'subsample': [.5, .75]
             }

model = GradientBoostingRegressor()

# Create a single validation split
val_prop = .2
n_val_rows = round(len(df_train) * val_prop)
val_starting_index = len(df_train) - n_val_rows
cv = PredefinedSplit([-1 if i < val_starting_index else 0 for i in df_train.index])


# Use PredefinedSplit in GridSearchCV
results = GridSearchCV(estimator = model,
                       cv=cv,
                       param_grid=param_grid,
                       verbose=True,
                       n_jobs=-1)

# Fit with all data
results.fit(df_train, y)

results.best_params_
```