# PredefinedSplit function in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to run `cross_val_score` in `sklearn` with a split supplied by me. The `sklearn` documentation gives [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.PredefinedSplit.html) the following example:

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> test_fold = [0, 1, -1, 1]
>>> ps = PredefinedSplit(test_fold)
>>> ps.get_n_splits()
2
>>> print(ps)       
PredefinedSplit(test_fold=array([ 0,  1, -1,  1]))
>>> for train_index, test_index in ps.split():
...    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
TRAIN: [1 2 3] TEST: [0]
TRAIN: [0 2] TEST: [1 3]
```

I am having troubles with understanding this example. In particular,

1. how does why does `ps.get_n_splits()` return 2 in this example; and
2. why does the `test_fold` array lead to the splits shown at the bottom of the code snippet?

Additionally, I would like to ask, in this case, if I pass the ps object to the `cross_val_score` function in `sklearn`, will it perform cross validation with these two splits?

Comment: You can have a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43766334/3374996)

Comment: Hi, many thanks. My question is a duplicate then.

Answer (score 5):

the number of split is the unique values in test_folder exclude (-1).

use this example using   test_fold = [0, 1, -1, 1],

- the zero index is 0, indicates the Test set is 0, the rest of 1, 2, 3 are Train set.

---

```
  --- > TRAIN: [1 2 3] TEST: [0]
```

- the 1st and 3rd index are 1, indicates the Test set are 1, 3, the rest of 0, 2 are Training set

---

```
  ---> TRAIN: [0 2] TEST: [1 3]
```

- the 2nd index is -1, indicates no train/test split.
- note, the integer value itself does make difference, so if test_folder = [5, 0, -1, 0], the split are the same

---

```
  --- > TRAIN: [1 2 3] TEST: [0]
```

finally , 
for a typical k-folder split, one can use test_fold = [0, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: Can you format your answer better to make it clearer?

Comment: This should be added to the Sklearn documentation.

Comment: I don't understand this explanation either. Why can't the scikit-learn documentation just show which rows of X actually go into the train data and which rows go into the test data? This should be a pretty straightforward concept, but explaining it with indices instead of actual hard examples is very unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

From the class PredefinedSplit(BaseCrossValidator)

```
self.unique_folds = np.unique(self.test_fold)
self.unique_folds = self.unique_folds[self.unique_folds != -1]
```

It first determines how many unique integer is in the 1D array test_fold.

In the case of your example, it is [0, 1, -1].

It then removes -1 from the array of unique 1D array giving [0, 1].This implies a 2-fold cross validation (len(self.unique_folds)). The distribution of indices is subjected to 3 constraints in this case.

1. Constraint 1: Since index 2 is excluded from the test set as it is
   set to -1, we are left with indices [0, 1, 3] to be distributed
   amongst the 2 arrays/lists that represent the 2-fold cross
   validation.
2. Constraint 2: Indices [1, 3] have to be together because they both
   have a value of 1 in the variable self.test_fold.
3. Constraint 3: The final constraint is that 0 and be together with
   [1, 3] as they have different values in self.test_fold.

Each chosen number cannot be replaced (technically this is also a constraint), therefore:
if 0 goes to TRAIN, then 2 must in be TRAIN as it is set to -1. Hence we have TRAIN=[0, 2] and the rest goes into TEST=[1, 3] due to the constraints mentioned in the previous sentence.

Due to the constraints, the only other possibility is TRAIN = [1, 3] + [2] and TEST=[0]