# specify scoring metric in GridSearch function with hypopt package in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, grid-search, hyperparameters

I'm using Gridsearch function from hypopt package to do my hyperparameter searching using specified validation set. The default metric for classification seems to be accuracy (not very sure). Here I want to use F1 score as the metric. I do not know where I should specify the metric. I looked at the documentation but kind of confused.

Does anyone who are familiar with hypopt package know how I can do this? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
from hypopt import GridSearch

log_reg_params = {"penalty": ['l1'], 'C': [0.001, 0.01]}
opt = GridSearch(model=LogisticRegression())
opt.fit(X_train, y_train, log_reg_params, X_val, y_val)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default metric of the `hypopt` package is the the `score()` function for whatever model you use, so in your case it is `LogisticRegression().score()` which defaults to accuracy.

If you upgrade the hypopt package to version 1.0.8 via `pip install hypopt --upgrade`, you can specify any metric of your choosing in the `scoring` parameter of `GridSearch.fit()`, for example, `fit(scoring='f1')`. Here is a simple working example based on your code that uses the F1 metric:

```
from hypopt import GridSearch

param_grid = {"penalty": ['l1'], 'C': [0.001, 0.01]}
opt = GridSearch(model=LogisticRegression(), param_grid = param_grid)
# This will use f1 score as the scoring metric that you optimize.
opt.fit(X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, scoring='f1')
```

`hypopt` supports most any scoring function that `sklearn` supports.

- For classification, `hypopt` supports these metrics (as strings): 'accuracy', 'brier_score_loss', 'average_precision', 'f1', 'f1_micro', 'f1_macro', 'f1_weighted', 'neg_log_loss', 'precision', 'recall', or 'roc_auc'.
- For regression, `hypopt` supports: "explained_variance", "neg_mean_absolute_error", "neg_mean_squared_error", "neg_mean_squared_log_error", "neg_median_absolute_error", "r2".

You can also create your own metric `your_custom_score_func(y_true, y_pred)` by wrapping it into an object like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
scorer = make_scorer(your_custom_score_func)
opt.fit(X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, scoring=scorer)
```

You can learn more in the `hypopt.GridSearch.fit()` docstring here:

- https://github.com/cgnorthcutt/hypopt/blob/master/hypopt/model_selection.py#L240

You can learn more about creating your own custom scoring metrics here:

- Example: https://github.com/cgnorthcutt/hypopt/blob/master/tests/test_core.py#L371
- Source code: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html

Comment: thank you so much for your detail answer!   One more question,  is hypopt same as hyperopt package?

Comment: Great - Mark and up vote it if it's the right answer. To answer your question - Not at all. Hypopt is a general package anytime you want to find the best setting of parameters for any model. Hypopt is the only python package for the simple case of optimizing parameters with a validation set. Whereas, hyperopt implements a tree search algorithm for a specific case of Bayesian Gaussian processes. There are a number of packages for Bayesian hyper-parameter optimization, and hyperopt may be a good one, I don't know as I haven't used it. @zesla

Comment: just upvoted. thanks a lot. I thought you are also the author of hyperopt

Comment: @zesla Note you'll want to upgrade to hypopt version 1.0.7, there was a minus sign error in 1.0.6. Fixed now :)