# Refit attribute of Grid Search with Pre defined split?

Tags: scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am using GridseachCV to tune the hyper parameters. I am having train,validation data separately. I am following predefined split approach to handle this (similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31949393/9460429)):

```
ps = PredefinedSplit(test_fold=your_test_fold)
```

then set `cv=ps` in `GridSearchCV`

If I set refit parameter as true,after all parameter tuning will my model be trained on whole data or only on train data?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> **refit** : boolean, string, or callable, default=True
>
> Refit an estimator using the best found parameters on the whole dataset.

Thus, yes, it will uses the whole dataset with the best hyperparameters. It does not matter whether you use the default (3 fold CV) or a split that comes from  `PredefinedSplit`.